# How to prevent TextView from being truncated

Tags: java, android

I have a TextView above a listView, and once the listView reaches the same height as the screen,(the moment some of the list items need to be scrolled-to to be seen) the text view turns into "..."

is there any way to prevent this from happening?
[image]

[image]

EDIT:
well, this is embarrassing...
the problem was that the server was returning '...' instead of the proper string, sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: post up xml code and add ss or gif

Comment: Please explain proper what you mean by when listview gets big

Comment: OK. Try this - Make TextView height 'Wrap content' and width match parent. Set ListView height to 0dp, not match parent. Use Linear layout it'll be done easily, but would suggest you to try doing it with Constraint Layout, that's more flexible.

Comment: @Ashish by big i mean that it takes all the space in the activity (and now you need to scroll to see all the items)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your question is no clear. i use recycler view hope this code will help you

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/color_white"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".AffectedCountries">
    
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="search"
            android:textSize="40dp"
           />
    
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/edtSearch"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
          android:id="@+id/recyclerAffectedCountries">
    
        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: in my case, i don't know what how the text height, so I set wrap content, can you try to do that as well?

Comment: the result would be the same beside that did my ans help you?